# How to write math with HTML like it were MathJax

Tags: html, css, mathjax

I've noticed that when I write math most of the symbols that I need can be expressed with simple HTML. However, I style like how MathJax styles the math. However, I guess that all what MathJax does is to apply some font, some size, some style and probably that could be done with HTML and CSS.

What CSS properties can I use to make my HTML math look like MathJax?